# Is my temp folder discoverable after image upload form?

Tags: php

I have a simple php image upload form that saves the images in a temporary folder, lets call it temp, and when the image is approved by me I manually copy it to the album folder.

My question is, if there is a way for someone or I don't know, a search engine maybe to find "guess" my temp folder and what images are inside ( before approve ).

Comment: Are you kiddin? you manually copy?

Comment: Nope. The temporary folder is outside the web root.

Comment: @Pekka Actually it is not. The temp is inside public_html

Comment: @Kaoukkos why is the temp folder inside the web root? It shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote it yourself:

> The temp is inside public_html

Doesn't that answer your question?

If this is not desirable, create a *.htaccess* file inside the temp folder, with this content:

```
Deny from all
```

Comment: Also, add `Options -Indexes` to stop Apache's indexing of that folder.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the location of the temp folder. If the folder lies outside the root directory of your server its not discoverable but if it lies inside the root directory it is discoverable. However you can limit the access to  your temp folder if its inside the root of the server through htaccess. Or you can place a index.php file inside the folder with a header redirect so that no one can see the file(image) list.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Currently is in the root directory. Can you tell me how is it discoverable ?

Comment: One of the way is to ping your server with requests using random keywords.